# Retrieving root ids gives empty dictionary

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

**Description of Code:**
I have two ids for ScreenList objects (proof_list and menu_list). When I click on a list item (instance_item), I want their associated parent's id. The check_id function should accomplish this by invoking get_id(instance_item.parent) to print their parent's id which would be either proof_list or menu_list.

**Problem:**
get_id doesn't retrieve self.root.ids full dictionary. I checked by printing the result, which gave an empty dictionary. Out of curiosity, I tried printing self.root.ids in my on_start method, and it gave a full dictionary of ids. I need to access self.root.ids in get_id, so it can check whether an instance is in that dictionary of ids and return its id if true.

**Questions:**
I believe this is an initialization issue, but I don't know where to start in fixing this. So my questions are:

1. Why does it give the full dictionary in the on_start method?
2. How can my get_id method retrieve the full id dictionary like the on_start method?

I know my issue concerns initialization. However, I am still learning and am confused about what to do, so I'd appreciate the help.

Here is a very simplified code example.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineListItem, TwoLineListItem, ThreeLineListItem, ThreeLineIconListItem, \
            OneLineIconListItem
from kivy.core.window import Window
from proof_nav import proof_helper
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
        
class ScreenList(ThemableBehavior, MDList):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()

    def check_id(self, instance_item):
        e1 = ProofApp()
        parent_id = e1.get_id(instance_item.parent)
        print(parent_id)

class ProofApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(proof_helper)
        return screen

    def on_start(self):
        print(self.root.ids)

    def get_id(self, instance_item):
        for id, widget in self.root.ids.items():
            if instance_item == widget:
                print(self.root.ids)
                return str(id)
        print(self.root.ids)
        return ""




ProofApp().run()
```

This is the string file I loaded:

```
proof_helper = """
            
Screen:
    MDNavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
                                
            Screen:
                name: 'menu'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "Menu Screen"
                        elevation: 8
                    
                    ScrollView:
                        ScreenList:
                            id: menu_list
                            screen_manager:screen_manager
                            OneLineListItem:
                                text: "Some Item"
                                on_release: self.parent.check_id(self)
                        
            
            Screen:
                name: 'screen2'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "Proofs"
                        elevation: 8

                    ScrollView:
                        ScreenList:
                            id: proof_list
                            screen_manager:screen_manager
                            OneLineListItem:
                                text: "Another Item"
                                on_release: self.parent.check_id(self)

"""
```

Comment: Show us how you called `get_id()` when it printed nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I just added more information to my post. Please let me know if it is still unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your `check_id()` method, the code:

```
e1 = ProofApp()
```

is creating a new instance of `ProofApp`. The new instance of `ProofApp` has no relation to the instance that you are running. You must use the currently running instance of the `App`, which you can get by calling `MDApp.get_running_app()`. So, your `check_id()` method should be something like:

```
def check_id(self, instance_item):
    # e1 = ProofApp()
    e1 = MDApp.get_running_app()
    parent_id = e1.get_id(instance_item.parent)
    print(parent_id)
```